# Apple Developer Account Hacked?

Tags: authentication, tls, web-browser, certificates

I just did a fresh install of Snow Leopard on a newly-formatted hard drive.

Logged into the iPhone Developer Page with Google Chrome (latest build) here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action

I login as usual, but instead of seeing my developer account info, I see someone else's.

Even if I click logout, it won't.

Anytime I click a link, I get a new page with usually a different name.

I stopped clicking links and quit the browser.

Then I logged in with my mobile, and there was no problem whatsoever.

I then cleared all my cookies, restarted the browser and I was back at seeing people's names once again.

A keychain issue?  Is my account being hacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the information about somebody else, then it is not your account which is being hacked; rather, you are (involuntarily) hacking the accounts of other people.

If the server accepts to send you pages with private information about other users, then the server has a problem (most probably a mere, mundane bug; no need to invoke actual malice here) and there is nothing you can do client-side (i.e. on *your* machines) to really solve that. If you are positive that you are obtaining information that you should not be able to get, your best bet is to report the problem to Apple.

Comment: I have to wait 40 mins before I can contact apple, but will do so shortly.  I tried to post screen shots, but I don't have enough rep.  ;)

Comment: Just curious, if someone was intentionally trying to gather information to penetrate a system, would this be a potential side-effect?

Comment: @Javy: hacking into a system means exploiting a bug somewhere in the structure or implementation of the system, which can trigger all the consequences that bugs may have -- including the kind of thing that you observe. But mere programming bugs, or even hardware failures such as bad RAM, can _also_ exhibit the same kind of symptom. And bad RAM is much more common than attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom.  I can log into my account now without issue.  However, I will do another re-format and install just to make sure.  =)

Comment: Just called them.  They're VERY interested, so I sent them a bunch of info.  Screen shots, console logs, the works.  Hopefully they will find out what happened.  Thanks again Tom.